# Why does the process handle the blocked signal?

Tags: c, linux

Consider the following program:

```
void handler(int signum){
    printf("handling %d\n", signum);
}

int main() {
    signal(SIGINT, handler);
    sigset_t *ss;
    sigemptyset(ss);
    sigaddset(ss, SIGINT);
    sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, ss, NULL);
    for(;;);
    return 0;
}
```

After running this program in the terminal, when I press ctrl-c, i always get "handling 2" as output, but I would expect to get no output, as SIGINT was previously blocked. Am I blocking SIGINT wrongly? Am I misunderstanding what it means for a signal to be blocked, by assuming that a blocked signal will not be handled on entering the process from kernel mode to user mode?

Comment: This may or may not be directly relevant, but you have undefined behaviour. You should declare `sigset_t ss;` and pass `&ss` to the sig functions. Currently you have an uninitialized pointer and are using a random area of memory for your signal set.

Comment: Ofcourse! How silly. That was the problem, it works now

Comment: Have an upvote for a clearly-answered and well-thought-out question, even if the solution isn't likely to help anyone else

Comment: And almost a MCVE (just needs a couple of `#include` and it will be complete)...

Comment: Note that `printf()` is not an async-signal-safe function and can't be safely called from within a signal handler.

Comment: @AndrewHenle seeing how this was written 7 minutes ago, you were probably typing that comment when I was reading the same statement from [this](https://www.amazon.com/Computer-Systems-Programmers-Perspective-3rd/dp/013409266X) book :D.

Answer (score 1):

@Useless has rightly answered the question stating that you are invoking UB by passing an uninitialized pointer to `sig*` functions.

As to why it works and doesn't crash or doesn't block SIGINT can be made clear if you add the line -

```
printf("%p", ss);
```

This will most probably print `(nil)` or `0`.

Luckily the uninitialized variable is set to `NULL` and from the documentation of [`sigprocmask`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sigprocmask.2.html)

> If `set` is `NULL`, then the signal mask is unchanged (i.e., how is
>          ignored), but the current value of the signal mask is nevertheless
>          returned in `oldest` (if it is not `NULL`).

So your blocking of `SIGINT` is in fact being ignored. But yes, you might also see crashes or some other (even correct behavior) if you are not lucky.